# NiFi: Extract Content of FlowFile and Add that Content to the Attributes

Tags: json, attributes, apache-nifi

I am generating random data from the following JSON/AVRO schema:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "namespace" : "test",
  "name" : "metro_data",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name" : "PersonID",
      "type" : "int"
},
{
  "name" : "TripStartStation",
  "type" : {
    "type" : "enum",
    "name" : "StartStation",
    "symbols" : ["WIEHLE_RESTON_EAST", "SPRING_HILL", "GREENSBORO"]    

    }
},
{
  "name" : "TripEndStation",
  "type" : {
    "type" : "enum",
    "name" : "EndStation",
    "symbols" : ["WIEHLE_RESTON_EAST", "SPRING_HILL", "GREENSBORO""]    

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above schema generates this, for example:

```
[ {
  "PersonID" : -1089196095,
  "TripStartStation" : "WIEHLE_RESTON_EAST",
  "TripEndStation" : "SPRING_HILL"
}
```

I want to take the `PersonID` number of the schema, and add it to the Attributes. Eg, the blank in this photo needs to pull the actual PersonID number generated from the flow:

[image]

**I have tried to use `EvaluateJSONPath` with the following configuration, and that's how I end up with the `empty string set` under `PersonalID`:**

[image]

Is my next processor `UpdateAttribute`? Not sure how to pull that content. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having **array of json message(s)**(ex: [...]) and You need to **split the array of json** into individual flowfiles using **SplitJson** processor with split expression as **$.***

Then use **EvaluateJsonProcessor** to extract **PersonID** value as a attribute.

**Flow:**

```
--> SplitJson --> EvaluateJsonPath--> other processors
```

For more details refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/224438/problem-with-evaluatejsonpath.html?childToView=224440#answer-224440) link regards to the same issue.

Comment: I see.. thanks for the answer. I'm confused on the `$.[0].PersonID` versus what comes after that in the link provided... there are two answers. Do I do the `[0]` and the regular `$.PersonID` in the same configuration?

Comment: @papelr, Ideal way would be `using SplitJson+EvaluateJsonPath` processors and if we use **[0]** then we referring to **only the first message in array of messages**.

Comment: Got it. Makes sense. Made it work. Appreciate the help